# Difficulty connecting arduino ethernet with PC using a switch

Tags: arduino-uno, switch, ethernet-shield

Facing difficulty connecting arduino ethernet(w5100) with PC using a switch (Dlink). When both are connected directly(p2p) using ethernet cable, arduino device can be pinged. However, when connected via switch - ping doesn't work, and both devices can't communicate with each other; updated the MAC addr. several times, nothing worked. How can this be resolved?

The same setup works when connected via a router instead of switch. But we need it to work with switch only.

Static ip has been assigned to both PC and arduino uno ethernet shield.

Comment: Do all link lights come on?

Comment: Yes, three lights are on, one for power, two for the two Ethernet cables.

Comment: Have you verified that the switch works?

Comment: Yes, pinged two PCs successfully via that switch and cables.

Comment: Are you using the same cable for direct connection and thru switch connection? They are different ...

Comment: @Alterno, cables are the same.

Comment: I think the w5100 works at 10MBs, so is the switch you are using compatible with 10MB/s?

Comment: @CodeGorilla Yes, the switch supports that speed.

Comment: @user3126972 - Damn.... The only other thing I can think about is there used to be two types of cable, crossed and straight.  You would use a straight cable to go from a device to a switch and a crossed cable to do P2P.  With some modern devices it doesn't matter because they auto-cross.  Its a long shot, but it might be worth checking (Google to work out how to spot the difference).    Could it be related to duplex?  I haven't looked at the datasheet for the W5100.  Does it support full duplex?  Is it supporting full duplex (can you even tell)?

Comment: @CodeGorilla, both the cables in use are straight one. Using the same cables I was able to ping two laptops through that switch. Regarding FullDuplex mode - yes, w5100 supports that, google 'W5100_Datasheet_v1_1_6.pdf'

Comment: What type of D-link switch is it? Is the switch a managed switch?

Comment: Is there an IP conflict? ie. does another device on the network have the same IP address assigned that you have on the PC or Arduino? What does `arp -a` on the PC say about the Arduino IP address? If there's no IP conflicts, it could be your arp cache on either device isn't being updated. To reset the Arduino, just reboot it. To clear the arp cache on the PC, just do a search for "clear arp cache" along with your OS type (or reboot).